# Is it always true that the edit distance of two strings is equal to the edit distance of their substrings?

Tags: levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

Suppose we have two strings:

1. ccttgg
2. gacgct

The edit distance of these two strings is 6.

Possible substrings are:

1. cctt--
2. gacg--

Their edit distance is 4.

The remaining parts to equal the original two strings are:

1. ----gg
2. ----ct

and their edit distance is 2.

So 4+2=6, that is the original edit distance.

Is this type of assumption always correct?

If it's not, is there a way to compute the edit distance between two strings using the edit distance of their substrings?

---

Edit: to be clearer my definition of edit distance is the Levenshtein distance with a cost of 1 for insertion, deletion and replace if the characters are not the same and 0 if the characters are equal.
I'm **not** considering the Damerau distance with transpositions.

Answer (score 1):

No

### Counterexample

Consider the strings:

1. aba
2. bab

They have an edit distance of 2 by deleting an "a" from the front and adding a "b" to the end.

If these are broken into substrings such as

1. ab, a
2. ba, b

then the first substrings have an edit distance of 2 and the second substrings have an edit distance of 1 for a total of 3.

Comment: I'm not considering swap/transposition like the Damerau distance

Comment: Updated to provide a counterexample for Levenshtein distance.

Comment: Thank you, I already had some serious doubts. Do you know a way to compute an edit distance by splitting the two initial strings into substrings?

Comment: If you don't allow only substitutions, then that property would hold.  Otherwise, I don't think you can split substrings and consider them independent.  The [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Iterative_with_full_matrix) does involve finding the distance between prefixes of the strings, so that may be relevant.